# How to remove or hide a div, which is inside an IFRAME that pulls an external link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

var ifrm = document.createElement("iframe");
 var linkFrm = "https://ExternalLink/";

Example:

```
        var x = linkFrm.document.getElementsByClassName("class");
        x.style.height = "0px";
        x.style.width = "0px";
```

Comment: Is the parent page (the page hosting iframe) and the child page (the page inside the iframe) both on the same domain?

Comment: I think so @zer00ne

Answer (score 0):

If something is inside an `iframe`, and you don't have the access to the `iframe`'s original location, you simply can't manipulate elements inside it.

Comment: Is there any way to override another div, as soon as it loads?

Comment: No, since `iframe` is basically another website. Simple rule: if it's in a external `iframe` you can't manipulate it.